# How to prevent AlertDialog using custom theme from appearing fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-alertdialog, android-styles, presentation

I am using a custom style for my `AlertDialog`s, but it is making them appear fullscreen.  I've searched around, but I could only seem to find people *wanting* to make it fullscreen...

Here is my style

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="AlertDialog.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/material_white</item>
</style>
```

And one of my `AlertDialog`s.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext(), R.style.MyDialog)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle(this.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.reset) + "?")
            .setMessage(this.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.AreYouSure))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), (dialog, which) -> {
                reset();
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.notReally), (dialog, which) ->{
                //Do nothing
            })
            .show();
```

And this is what it looks like.  I cannot figure out why it takes up the entire screen.  It should look like an `AlertDialog` just with custom colors.

[image]

Comment: make sure height of your parent layout of reset.xml in `wrap_content`.

Comment: add   <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> to your style

Comment: @deepakjohn141 This did the trick, thank you a ton.

Comment: @WilliamSmith glad to jhelp you, i have added this as answer,please select it as answer

Comment: @deepakjohn141 gotchya

Answer (score 8):

```
add <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> to MyDialog style
```